# React-Hook-Form unexpected behavior with Multi Level Nested Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Lately i discovered the react-hook-from plugin which on the first sight seem to be perfect to start using and replace other plugins due to its great performance.

After using the plugin for some really simple forms i came across a complicated form that i wish to handle with the plugin. My form is based on a nested object which has the following structure. *(Typescript definition)*

```
type model = {
   tag: string;
   visible: boolean;
   columns?: (modelColumn | model)[];
}

type modelColumn = {
   property: string;
}
```

So in order to handle to handle a n-level nested form i created the following components.

```
const initialData = {
    ...
    datasource: {
        tag: "tag1",
        visible: true,
        columns: [
            {
                property: "property",
            },
            {
                property: "property1",
            }, 
            {
                tag: "tag2",
                visible: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        property: "property",
                    }, 
                    {
                        tag: "tag3",
                        visible: false,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                property: "property",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                entity: "tag4",
                visible: false,
            }
        ],
    },
    ...
}

export const EditorContent: React.FunctionComponent<EditorContentProps> = (props: any) => {
   const form = useForm({
        mode: 'all',
        defaultValues: initialData,
    });

    return (
        <FormProvider {...form}>
                <form>
                    <Handler 
                        path="datasource"
                    />
                </form>
        </FormProvider>
    );
}
```

In the above component the main form is created loaded with initial data. *(I provided an example value)*. The `Handler` component has the login of recursion with the path property to call nested logic of the form data type. Here is the sample implementation.

```
...
import { get, isNil } from "lodash";
import { useFieldArray, useForm, useFormContext, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";
...

export type HandlerProps = {
    path: string;
    index?: number;
    ...
}

export const Handler: React.FunctionComponent<HandlerProps> = (props) => {
    const { path, index, onDelete, ...rest } = props;

    const { control } = useFormContext();

    const name = isNil(index)? `${path}` :`${path}[${index}]`;
  
    const { fields, append, insert, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control: control,
        name: `${name}.columns`
    });

    ...

    const value = useWatch({
        control,
        name: `${name}`,
    });

    ...
    const addHandler = () => {
        append({ property: null });
    };

    console.log(`Render path ${name}`);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <FormField name={`${name}.tag`} defaultValue={value.tag}>
                        <Input
                            label={`Tag`}
                        />
                    </FormField>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                     <FormField defaultValue={value.visible} name={`${name}.visible`} >
                         <Switch />
                     </FormField>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <button onClick={addHandler}>Add Column Property</button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {
                fields && (
                    fields.map((field: any, _index: number) => {
                        if (field.property !== undefined) {
                            return (
                                <Column 
                                    path={`${name}.columns`}
                                    index={_index}
                                    control={control}
                                    fields={fields}
                                    onDelete={() => remove(_index) }
                                />
                            )
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <Handler 
                                    path={`${name}.columns`}
                                    index={_index}
                                />
                            )
                        }
                    })
                )
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Essentially the Handler Component uses the form's context and call itself if it should render a nested object of the form like datasource.columns[x] which the register to useFieldArray to get it's columns. Everything so far works fine. I render the complete tree *(if i can say)* like object form correctly.

For reference here is the code of the Column Component as also for the formField helper component FormField.

```
export const Column: React.FunctionComponent<ColumnProps> = (props) => {
    const { fields, control, path, index, onDelete } = props;

    const value = useWatch({
        control,
        name: `${path}[${index}]`,
        defaultValue: !isNil(fields[index])? fields[index]: { 
            property: null,
        }
    });

    console.log(`Render of Column ${path} ${value.property}`);
    
    return (
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <button onClick={onDelete}>Remove Property</button>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <FormField name={`${path}[${index}].property`} defaultValue={value.property}>
                    <Input
                        label={`Column Property name`}
                    />
                </FormField>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
}


export type FormFieldProps = {
    name: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    validation?: any;
    defaultValue?: any;
    children?: any;
};

export const FormField: React.FunctionComponent<FormFieldProps> = (props) => {
    const { 
        children, 
        name, 
        validation,
        defaultValue,
        disabled,
    } = props;

    const { errors, control, setValue  } = useFormContext();

    return (
        <Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            defaultValue={defaultValue? defaultValue: null}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={props => {
                return (
                    React.cloneElement(children, { 
                        ...children.props, 
                        ...{
                            disabled: disabled || children.props.disabled,
                            value: props.value,
                            onChange: (v:any) => {
                                props.onChange(v);
                                setValue(name, v, { shouldValidate: true });
                            },
                        } 
                    })
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

The problem is when i remove a field from the array. The Handler component re-renders having correct values on the `fields` data. But the values of useWatch have the initial data which leads to a wrong render with wrong fields being displayed an the forms starts to mesh up.

Is there any advice on how to render such a nested form the correct way. I guess this is not an issue from the react-hook-form but the implementation has an error which seems to cause the problem.